# Caml Join Field Type

Tags: caml, field-type

I'm having trouble using the Join via Caml.
In a way, I'm having trouble working with 1 field, that is "new window" that the field type is boolean.

My code looks like this:

```
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
StringBuilder sbJoin = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbProj = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sbQuery = new StringBuilder();

using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://localhost/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList oList = web.Lists["shortcuts users"];
        SPListItemCollection items = null;

        sbJoin.Append("<Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='shortcuts'>");
        sbJoin.Append("<Eq>");
        sbJoin.Append("<FieldRef Name='shortcut' RefType='Id'/><FieldRef List='shortcuts' Name='ID'/>");
        sbJoin.Append("</Eq>");
        sbJoin.Append("</Join>");

        sbQuery.Append("<Where>");
        sbQuery.Append("<Eq><FieldRef Name='user' /><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Eq>");
        sbQuery.Append("</Where>");
        sbQuery.Append("<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='order' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>");

        sbProj.Append("<Field Name='shortcutName' Type='Lookup' List='Atalhos' ShowField='Title'/>");
        sbProj.Append("<Field Name='shortcutLink' Type='Lookup' List='Atalhos' ShowField='link'/>");
        sbProj.Append("<Field Name='shortcutNewWindow' Type='Boolean' List='Atalhos' ShowField='newWindow'/>");
        sbProj.Append("<Field Name='AtalhoContentTypeId' Type='Lookup' List='Atalhos' ShowField='ContentTypeId' />");

        oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='order'/><FieldRef Name='shortcutName'/><FieldRef Name='shortcutLink'/><FieldRef Name='shortcutNewWindow'/>";
        oQuery.Joins = sbJoin.ToString();
        oQuery.Query = sbQuery.ToString();
        oQuery.ProjectedFields = sbProj.ToString();

        items = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, order: {1} - shortcut Name: {2}, shortcut Link: {3} shortcut New Window: {4}",
                        item["Title"],
                        item["order"],
                        item["shortcutName"],
                        item["shortcutLink"],
                        item["shortcutNewWindow"]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", items.Count);
        }
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem is in this line:

```
sbProj.Append("<Field Name='shortcutNewWindow' Type='Boolean' List='Atalhos' ShowField='newWindow'/>");
```

If I use the boolean type of the field as it returns this error:
0x80070057

Now if I use the field type as another Lookup returns this error:
Value does not fall within the expected range

What type of field, I have to use in order to function?

Answer (score 1):

The `ListAlias` in the `Join` clause should be the same as the `List` of your projected fields.

[Similar error](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/a37dfc2f-17ab-4849-9150-7b1e4fdbd71b)